# Angular Firebase Firestore get document ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My Firebase Firestore database is like this:

```
Collection:orders
    DocumentID: (autogenerated)
         Document: orderName: string
```

Variables declared like this:

```
    orderCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Order>
    orders: Observable<Order[]>
```

I am getting all 'orders' like this:

```
orderCollection = this.afs.collection('orders');
orders = this.orderCollection.valueChanges();
```

I am then printing the orders like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let o of orders | async">
    <td>{{o.orderName}}</td>
    <td><a (click)="editOrder(o.$key)">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

I everything is working perfect up to the edit part.

For edit: how to I send back the document ID of the order? I want to send the order document ID back so I can then edit it. With the realtime database you could do something with $key, but not with the firestore. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In AngularFirestore it is simply `document.id`. But for this to work you must use `snapshotChanges` instead of `valueChanges`. So:

```
orders = this.orderCollection.snapshotChanges();
```

And then:

```
<tr *ngFor="let o of orders | async">
    <td>{{o.data().orderName}}</td>
    <td><a (click)="editOrder(o.id)">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

Inspired by: [Firestore Getting documents id from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900430/firestore-getting-documents-id-from-collection) and [Get Collections with Document Ids Included](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-advanced-usage-angularfire/#5-Get-Collections-with-Document-Ids-Included).

Comment: I have the variables declared as follows:<br><br>
  orderCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Order><br>
  orders: Observable<Order[]><br><br>

    this.orderCollection = this.afs.collection('orders');<br>
    this.orders = this.orderCollection.snapshotChanges();<br><br>

but with the snapshotChanges(), I am getting the error on this.orders: <br>type 'Observable<DocumentChangeAction<Order>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Order[]>'.
<br>
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Import this

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and in your interface make sure contain id

```
export interface Order{
  id?:string
  foo1?: string
  foo2?: string
  foo3?: string
}
```

and your function look like this

```
this.orderCollection = this.afs.collection<Order>('orders');
 this.orders = this.orderCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(kazi => {
      return kazi.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;

          return { id, ...data };
      });
      })
  );
```

get result

```
  this.orders.forEach(order =>{
      console.log(order)   
})
```

I hope that will help