# Getting the documentid in Angular Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I cannot get the document Id in Firestore. I create a randomly generated document id, however, to add a delete function I need that randomly generated ID and cant figure out how to access it.
I could also create a custom document id, however, I cannot figure that out either and get errors.
So im trying to either find a way to access the document ID the document ID for each item in the list that is printed out in the for loop of the html. Or to find a way to create the doc ids as something unique such as a parsed image url.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { WebcamImage } from 'ngx-webcam';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { visionApi } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthorizationService } from '../auth-service.service';
import { AngularFirestoreModule, AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { BusinessCardServiceService } from '../business-card-service.service';

interface BusinessCard {

  imageUrl: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  fullText: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './web-cam.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web-cam.component.scss']
})
export class WebCamComponent implements OnInit {
  public showWebcam = true;
  public webcamImage: WebcamImage = null;
  private trigger: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  public base64;
  public url = `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${visionApi.key}`;
  public parsedImage;
  email: string;
  fullText: string;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  uid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('uid'));

  private cardCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<BusinessCard>;
  businessCards: Observable<BusinessCard[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public router: Router,
              private dashService: AuthorizationService,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              public bcService: BusinessCardServiceService) {

  }
  public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
    this.base64 = this.webcamImage.imageAsBase64;
    this.imageUrl = this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl;
    this.parsedImage = this.base64.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, '');
    const request: any = {
      'requests': [
        {
          'image': {
            'content': this.parsedImage
          },
          'features': [
            {
              'type': 'TEXT_DETECTION'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    console.log(request);
    console.log(this.parsedImage);
    this.http.post(
      this.url,
      request
    ).subscribe((results: any) => {
      console.log('RESULTS');
      console.log(results);
      console.log(results.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text);
      this.fullText = results.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text;
      this.email = JSON.stringify(this.fullText.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+/));
      this.name = JSON.stringify(this.fullText.match(/([A-Za-z]+),\\s*([A-Za-z]+)\\s*([A-Za-z]+)/));
      this.phone = JSON.stringify(this.fullText.match(/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/));
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      this.bcService.create(this.fullText, this.email, this.name, this.phone, this.imageUrl, this.uid);



  });

  }
  public ngOnInit(): void {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      this.cardCollection = this.afs.collection<BusinessCard>('Users/' + this.uid + '/BusinessCards' + this.uid);
      this.businessCards = this.cardCollection.valueChanges();

  }

  public triggerSnapshot(): void {
    this.trigger.next();
  }

  public get triggerObservable(): Observable<void> {
    return this.trigger.asObservable();
  }
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestoreModule, AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { WebcamImage } from 'ngx-webcam';

interface BusinessCard {

  imageUrl: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  fullText: string;
}



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BusinessCardServiceService {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  fullText: string;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  public webcamImage: WebcamImage = null;
  cardObj: string;
  cardref: AngularFirestoreCollection<BusinessCard>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  cardRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<BusinessCard>;
  card$: Observable<BusinessCard[]>;

  create(fullText: string, email: string, name: string, phone: string, imageUrl: string, uid: string) {
    this.fullText = fullText;
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.afs.doc('Users/' + this.uid).set({
    });
    this.afs.collection('Users/' + this.uid + '/BusinessCards' + this.uid).add({
      fullText: this.fullText,
      name: this.name,
      phone: this.phone,
      imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
      email: this.email,
      uid: this.uid
    });


  }

  getCard() {
    return this.afs.collection('Users/' + this.uid + '/BusinessCards' + this.uid).snapshotChanges();
  }

 // deletePolicy(cardId: string){
 //   this.cardId = cardId
 //   this.afs.doc('Users/' + this.uid + '/BusinessCards' + this.uid + this.cardId).delete();

}
```

```
<ul>
    <div *ngFor='let card of businessCards | async'>
        <div>{{card.name}} <button class="updateButton">Update Name</button></div>
        <div>{{card.email}} <button class="updateButton">Update Email</button></div>
        <div>{{card.phone}} <button class="updateButton">Update Phone Number</button></div>
        <img [src]='card.imageUrl' />
        <div><button class="DeleteButton">Delete Card</button></div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[snapshotChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/7eb3e51022c7381dfc94ffb9e12555065f060639/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges) is the function that returns a document metadata containing the document id. [Here is an implementation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/7eb3e51022c7381dfc94ffb9e12555065f060639/docs/firestore/collections.md#example) of that function in Angular. Once the ID is obtained, deleting data can be done following [these guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900430/firestore-getting-documents-id-from-collection) for a few responses on a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `valueChanges` to subscribe to this query in `WebCamComponent`

```js
this.cardCollection = this.afs.collection<BusinessCard>('Users/' + this.uid + '/BusinessCards' + this.uid);
this.businessCards = this.cardCollection.valueChanges();
```

But `valueChanges` doesn't [return all the metadata](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechangesidfield-string), it only returns the value.  You want to use `snapshotChanges` ([see here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges)) to get the key as well.

You will need to unpack the result, of course to include the `id` in the BusinessCard.  The id will be on the `doc.id` member of the result, and the rest of the fields you already have will be `doc.data` member.

As this returns a lot more metadata (not only the id, but also what kind of change was involved, all in a [`DocumentChangeAction[]`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#the-documentchangeaction-type)), you will need code similar to the example in the document above to unpack it (Note: I have not tested this exact example in the full context of your code, but the general form should work for you):

```js
    this.businessCards = this.cardCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as BusinessCard;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;  // assumes member `id` is on BusinessCard
        return data;
      }))
    );
```